# Redirect traffic that doesn't match a particular path

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have an old site which is no longer used and need to redirect traffic elsewhere. One problem I have though is that one particular area of the site needs to remain available to support previous customers who have purchased items from the site.

I would like to do this with .htaccess but my regex knowledge is quite limited.

Basically I would like to redirect all site requests which do not have the support path (which can have additional segments on the end):

```
http://www.example.com/support
http://www.example.com/support/contact
http://www.example.com/support/ticket
```

However the following examples (two of many) should be redirected to the new site:

```
http://www.example.com
http://www.example.com/projects
```

So far I have only figure out how to redirect requests with no additional parameters using:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.newsite.com/ [L,R=301]
```

I know that what I need is basically something like this:

```
IF url does not contain www.example.com/support
THEN redirect
```

I just don't know how to write it with regex / .htaccess

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to redirect all URLs without `support` in the path. ¿Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier with mod_rewrite directives, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/support/?   [NC]
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$    http://www.newsite.com/$1    [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache has [great documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/) for `mod_rewrite`. It really is worth a read.

In your special case, to avoid a redirect for all paths starting with `support`, you can use a `RewriteCond` directive, i.e.:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/support
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: hmmm... the redirect works but it seems to still redirect me when I hit the /support URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(support/?.*)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The first one "forwards" your `support/` request to `support/...` and finishes the processing of the RewriteRules. And the second should forward all your other queries to the new site.

Comment: I seem to be getting an `Internal Server Error` when the first condition is matched.

Comment: I think I missed some `$` signs. I've added it in my answer.